# how to find who created an appointment in a shared outlook calendar?

Tags: outlook, calendar, shared, organizer

We are using a shared outlook calendar to which many people can add appointments. **I am trying to figure out who added an appointment programmatically.** This information will show up at the right-bottom corner of the appointment information window if I double-click the item, suppose it has not been changed by someone else. So it should be stored somewhere.

However, I cannot find it in the [AppointmentItem object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem). The Organizer seems what I want, but on the late version of outlook, it always stores the name of the shared account, rather the name of the person who created the item.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy/home.htm) gave me the hint for the following solution:

```
AppointmentItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x4038001F")
```

The input to GetProperty method is so-called [MAPITags](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/enum_MAPITags.htm). The meaning of above tag is `PR_CreatorSimpleDispName_W`